# Header file cannot be found in my C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just downloaded some files (TinyXML.h) and added the files next to my other header and cpp files. I also added the line to my main cpp file

```
#include "tinyxml.h"
```

however I still get the error

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tinyxml.h': No such file or directory
```

Now if I add the exact path of the file in the properties of my project ("add additional include directories") then I do not get this error. I wanted to know how I could resolve this issue. Since VS2010 has no issue finding my other header files that are placed right next to it why is it having a problem with this one ?

Comment: You downloaded `TinyXML.h` but included `tinyxml.h`? That might be it.

Comment: When you mean by "adding the file" did you "drag and drop" because this technically does not add files to your project, but rather references them.

Comment: copy pasted the header and relevant source files

Comment: They work when i insert their new directory in VS2010 .Why do i need to do that when they are right next to my other header files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I wouldn't just copy the 3rd party headers over to your project directory. Just keep them in their own own folder and add that folder to the additional include directories.

Second, if the header is in the same place as the source file, the `include` should work as-is. So I don't think that's it (assuming you got the capitalization right). I think you're actually looking at a different source file than the one you have in that directory. (you can tell this is the case by hovering over the file's tab in Visual Studio and checking the path or opening the source file you think you included the file in). I'm 99% sure you're compiling the wrong cpp file.

Comment: Yeah that was the reason. I didnt know you could get the relative path from the files. Thanks

Comment: I will also move my library files to a separate folder